# IOS App crashed on iTunes' version, but works fine on local simulator & real device testing

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, simulator

I have an IOS app successfully uploaded to iTunes,
the app has also been testing successfully on both local simulator & real device.

however, when I download the app from App Store (with same device, same OS version), the app will load initially, and crash on a specific view.

I got the following error message from my NewRelic Crash Analytic:

SIGSEGV
in 0x10024d050 0 + 4297379920

This seems to be a very unusual error, since the local copy should be exactly the same as the one I uploaded to App store.

Any advice is appreciated,

thanks!

---

Stack Trace:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  1

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   MyXcodeProject                  0x00000001000fbfe4 0x100098000 + 409572
1   UIKit                           0x0000000188e90954 0x188e80000 + 67924
2   UIKit                           0x0000000188e90664 0x188e80000 + 67172
3   UIKit                           0x00000001895841cc 0x188e80000 + 7356876
4   UIKit                           0x000000018918b78c 0x188e80000 + 3192716
5   UIKit                           0x00000001891a6b4c 0x188e80000 + 3304268
6   UIKit                           0x00000001891a8f64 0x188e80000 + 3313508
7   UIKit                           0x0000000188f85b38 0x188e80000 + 1071928
8   UIKit                           0x0000000188fb3ac0 0x188e80000 + 1260224
9   UIKit                           0x0000000188fb2998 0x188e80000 + 1255832
10  UIKit                           0x0000000188ee54b4 0x188e80000 + 414900
11  Foundation                      0x000000018556cba0 0x185484000 + 953248
12  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018463ac1c 0x18455c000 + 912412
13  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018463a8cc 0x18455c000 + 911564
14  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184638318 0x18455c000 + 901912
15  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001845651f0 0x18455c000 + 37360
16  GraphicsServices                0x000000018d9876f8 0x18d97c000 + 46840
17  UIKit                           0x0000000188ef6108 0x188e80000 + 483592
18  MyXcodeProject                  0x00000001001ed04c 0x100098000 + 1396812
19  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000195cd6a04 0x195cd4000 + 10756
```

---

The following will be where this error occurs:

import UIKit
import CoreData

class ContactListViewController: UIViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate, WYPopoverControllerDelegate, CreateGroupVcDelegate, ContactListDetailVcDelegate, SelectAddContactsTableVcDelegate, SelectContactsVcDelegate  {

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var btnEdit: UIButton!

var fetchedResultsController_Group: NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()
var fetchedResultsController_Contact: NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()
var fetchedResult_GroupAndContact = [GroupAndContact]()



// Select Group Index
var selectedGroupIndex = Int()
// Selected group ID
var selectedGroupId = Int()

var contactIndex = Int()

// BOOL indicator
var isEditMode : Bool = false

// Popover Controller
var popoverController_CreateGroupVc = WYPopoverController()
var popoverController_ContactListDetailVc = WYPopoverController()
var popoverController_SelectAddContactsTableVc = WYPopoverController()



override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    MainMenuItem.setupMenuBtn(self)

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Contact"
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Avenir Light", size: 18)!,  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.navigationBarTitle()]

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // Listeners
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "updateSavedDataContact_Success", name:"updateSavedDataContact_Success", object: nil)

    // Default index 1 as the selected item for the colleciton view
    selectedGroupIndex = 1

    updateDataSource()


}

func updateDataSource ()
{
    getFetchedResultController_Group()

    let modIndexPath : NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: selectedGroupIndex_data(), inSection: 0)

    var result = self.fetchedResultsController_Group.objectAtIndexPath(modIndexPath) as? Group
    selectedGroupId = result!.id as Int

    getFetchedResultController_Contact(result!.id as Int)

    self.collectionView.reloadData()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

// #Listener Methods
func updateSavedDataContact_Success ()
{
    updateDataSource()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func getFetchedResultController_Group ()
{


    let appDel : AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let moc: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()


    //3 - set the correct table
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Group", inManagedObjectContext: moc)
    fetchRequest.entity = entity

    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20


    /*
    // Filter
    let predicate1 : NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "is_incoming_all == \(mytaskValue)", argumentArray: nil)
    let predicate12 : NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == \"Nice Group\"", argumentArray: nil)

    let predicateArray : Array = [predicate1]

    let compoundPredicate : NSPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate.andPredicateWithSubpredicates(predicateArray)
    fetchRequest.predicate = compoundPredicate */



    let sectionSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "sort_id", ascending: true)

    let sortDescriptors = [sectionSortDescriptor] //, secondSortDescriptor]

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors

    //4 - navigate in relationship to group by time
    let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    self.fetchedResultsController_Group = aFetchedResultsController

    var error: NSError? = nil
    if !self.fetchedResultsController_Group.performFetch(&error) {
        abort()
    }
}

func getFetchedResultController_Contact (groupId: Int)
{
    getFetchedResultController_GroupAndContact(groupId)


    let appDel : AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let moc: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()


    //3 - set the correct table
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Contact", inManagedObjectContext: moc)
    fetchRequest.entity = entity

    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20


    // Filter

    var strForPredicate = String()
    strForPredicate = strForPredicate + "id == nil"
    for (var i = 0; i < fetchedResult_GroupAndContact.count; i++)
    {
        strForPredicate = strForPredicate + " OR id == \(fetchedResult_GroupAndContact[i].contact_id)"
    }

    //"groupAndContact.group_id == \(groupId) AND groupAndContact.contact_id == id"
    let predicate1 : NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: strForPredicate, argumentArray: nil)
    //let predicate1 : NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == SUBQUERY(groupAndContact, $gac, ANY $gac.group_id == \(groupId)).contact_id", argumentArray: nil)
    //let predicate2 : NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == \"Nice Group\"", argumentArray: nil)
    let predicateArray : Array = [predicate1]

    let compoundPredicate : NSPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate.andPredicateWithSubpredicates(predicateArray)
    fetchRequest.predicate = compoundPredicate



    let sectionSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)

    let sortDescriptors = [sectionSortDescriptor] //, secondSortDescriptor]

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors

    //4 - navigate in relationship to group by time
    let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    self.fetchedResultsController_Contact = aFetchedResultsController

    var error: NSError? = nil
    if !self.fetchedResultsController_Contact.performFetch(&error) {
        abort()
    }
}

func getFetchedResultController_GroupAndContact (groupId: Int)
{

     var managedObjectContext : NSManagedObjectContext? = {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
        if let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext {
            return managedObjectContext
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
        }()


    let fetchRequest1 = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "GroupAndContact")

    // Filter
    let predicate11 : NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "group_id == \(groupId)", argumentArray: nil)
    //let predicate12 : NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == \"Nice Group\"", argumentArray: nil)
    let predicateArray1 : Array = [predicate11]

    let compoundPredicate1 : NSPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate.andPredicateWithSubpredicates(predicateArray1)
    fetchRequest1.predicate = compoundPredicate1

    if let fetchResults1 = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest1, error: nil) as? [GroupAndContact] {

        fetchedResult_GroupAndContact = fetchResults1

    }




}




// #Buttons
@IBAction func btnDeleteGroup(sender: AnyObject)
{
    var indexPath = NSIndexPath()
    indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(self.collectionView.convertPoint(sender.center, fromView: sender.superview))!

    let modIndexPath : NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row-1, inSection: indexPath.section)

    var result = self.fetchedResultsController_Group.objectAtIndexPath(modIndexPath) as? Group



    // Reset selectedItemIndex Logic : Delete
    if (indexPath.row > selectedGroupIndex)
    {
        // selectedGroupIndex stays the same
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == selectedGroupIndex)
    {
        selectedGroupIndex = 1
    }
    else if (indexPath.row <= selectedGroupIndex)
    {
        selectedGroupIndex = selectedGroupIndex-1
    }


    /*
    if(selectedGroupIndex == returnLastItemIndexInCollectionView())
    {
        selectedGroupIndex = 1
    }
    */

    AlertManager.instance.alertDeleteGroupConfirmation(result!.name, okBlock: {

        // EXE
        DataManager.instance.deleteSpecificGroup( Int(result!.id) )

        }, cancelBlock: {})


    btnEditSupport()


}


//temp
@IBAction func btnEdit(sender: AnyObject)
{
    btnEditSupport()
}


func btnEditSupport()
{
    isEditMode = !isEditMode

    if(isEditMode)
    {
        btnEdit.setTitle("Done", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
    else
    {
        btnEdit.setTitle("Edit", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
    updateDataSource()

}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/


// #CollectionView Delegate

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController_Group.sections![section] as NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo

    return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects + 1

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


    var cell: ContactListVcCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as ContactListVcCollectionViewCell


    /*
    var isSelected = false


    for (var i = 0; i < arySelectedItemsIndex.count; i++)
    {
    if(indexPath.row == arySelectedItemsIndex[i])
    {
    isSelected = true
    }

    }
    */
    var isSelected = false


    if(indexPath.row == selectedGroupIndex)
    {
        isSelected = true
    }




    // Display
    var img = UIImage(named: "icon_delete.png")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
    cell.imgDeleteGroup.image = img
    cell.imgDeleteGroup.tintColor = UIColor.MBHred()


    if ( indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        var img = UIImage(named: "icon_add.png")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
        cell.imgGroupIcon.image = img
        cell.imgGroupIcon.tintColor = UIColor.groupIconAddGroup()

        cell.lbGroupName.text = "Add"
        cell.lbGroupName.textColor = UIColor.groupIconAddGroup()

        // hide delete button for [add group] & [All Contact]
        cell.imgDeleteGroup.hidden = true
        cell.btnDeleteGroup.hidden = true

    }
    else
    {

        let modIndexPath : NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row-1, inSection: indexPath.section)

        var result = self.fetchedResultsController_Group.objectAtIndexPath(modIndexPath) as? Group


        cell.lbGroupName.text = result?.name
        cell.lbGroupName.textColor = UIColor.groupIconNotSelected()



        var img = UIImage(named: "group_\(result!.icon_id).png")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)

        // Display
        cell.imgGroupIcon.image = img
        cell.imgGroupIcon.tintColor = UIColor.groupIconNotSelected()





        // Cell selected or not
        if (isSelected)
        {
            cell.lbGroupName.textColor = UIColor.groupIconSelected()
            cell.imgGroupIcon.tintColor = UIColor.groupIconSelected()
        }
        else
        {
            cell.lbGroupName.textColor = UIColor.groupIconNotSelected()
            cell.imgGroupIcon.tintColor = UIColor.groupIconNotSelected()
        }





        // show delete button for [add group] & [All Contact]
        // if the editmode is true


        if (isEditMode && indexPath.row > 1)
        {
            cell.imgDeleteGroup.hidden = false
            cell.btnDeleteGroup.hidden = false
        }
        else
        {
            cell.imgDeleteGroup.hidden = true
            cell.btnDeleteGroup.hidden = true
        }

    }





    return cell
}



// NOTE: Since the first item is always "Add", remeber to use Index.row-1 to fetch from Array

/*
    let modIndexPath : NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row-1, inSection: indexPath.section)
*/

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {




    if ( indexPath.row == 0 )
    {
        // Add Group


        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CreateGroupViewController") as CreateGroupViewController

        vc.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.width-25, self.view.bounds.height*4/5)

        vc.loadView()
        vc.delegateCreateGroupVcDelegate = self


        vc.title = "Create a Group"
        vc.btnCancel.addTarget(self, action: Selector("dismissCreateGroupVc"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        /*
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        */



        popoverController_CreateGroupVc = WYPopoverController(contentViewController: vc)
        popoverController_CreateGroupVc.delegate = self
        popoverController_CreateGroupVc.presentPopoverFromRect(CGRectMake(self.collectionView.bounds.origin.x, self.collectionView.bounds.origin.y, self.collectionView.bounds.width, 50) , inView: self.view, permittedArrowDirections: WYPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)

    }
    else
    {
        selectedGroupIndex = indexPath.row

        // Choose from existing group

        let modIndexPath : NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row-1, inSection: indexPath.section)

        var result = self.fetchedResultsController_Group.objectAtIndexPath(modIndexPath) as? Group


        selectedGroupId = result!.id as Int
        getFetchedResultController_Contact(result!.id as Int)

        collectionView.reloadData()
        tableView.reloadData()

        println("result?.id = \(result?.id)")
    }



}


// #alertView Delegate

func alertView(alert: UIAlertView!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int)
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        if ((alert.textFieldAtIndex(0)?.text) != nil)
        {
            DataManager.instance.addGroup(alert.textFieldAtIndex(0)!.text, iconId: 1)
        }

    }

}




// #TableView Delegate

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    let sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController_Contact.sections![section] as NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo

    return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects + 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!,
    cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!
{
    let sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController_Contact.sections![indexPath.section] as NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo


    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as ContactListVcTableViewCell
    /*
    var isSelected = false


    for (var i = 0; i < arySelectedItemsIndex.count; i++)
    {
    if(indexPath.row == arySelectedItemsIndex[i])
    {
    isSelected = true
    }

    }
    */
    var isSelected = false


    if(indexPath.row == selectedGroupIndex)
    {
        isSelected = true
    }



    /*
    // Display
    var img = UIImage(named: "icon_delete.png")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
    cell.imgDeleteGroup.image = img
    cell.imgDeleteGroup.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    */


    // Last Row of the TableView : Add Button
    if (indexPath.row == sectionInfo.numberOfObjects)
    {
        var img = UIImage(named: "icon_add.png")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
        cell.imgAddContact.image = img
        cell.imgAddContact.tintColor = UIColor.groupIconAddGroup()

        cell.lbName.hidden = true
        cell.imgAddContact.hidden = false
        //cell.lbAddContact.hidden = false

        /*
        // hide delete button for [add group] & [All Contact]
        cell.imgDeleteGroup.hidden = true
        cell.btnDeleteGroup.hidden = true */

    }

    // Other Rows of the TableView : Display
    else
    {

        let modIndexPath : NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row, inSection: indexPath.section)

        var result = self.fetchedResultsController_Contact.objectAtIndexPath(modIndexPath) as? Contact


        cell.lbName.text = result?.name
        cell.lbName.textColor = UIColor.groupIconNotSelected()

        cell.lbName.hidden = false
        cell.imgAddContact.hidden = true

        /*
        //temp
        var img = UIImage(named: "group_\(result!.icon_url).png")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)

        // Display
        cell.imgGroupIcon.image = img
        cell.imgGroupIcon.tintColor = UIColor.groupIconNotSelected()
        */



        /*
        // Cell selected or not
        if (isSelected)
        {
            cell.lbGroupName.textColor = UIColor.groupIconSelected()
            cell.imgGroupIcon.tintColor = UIColor.groupIconSelected()
        }
        else
        {
            cell.lbGroupName.textColor = UIColor.groupIconNotSelected()
            cell.imgGroupIcon.tintColor = UIColor.groupIconNotSelected()
        }
        */


        /*

        // show delete button for [add group] & [All Contact]
        // if the editmode is true


        if (isEditMode)
        {
            cell.imgDeleteGroup.hidden = false
            cell.btnDeleteGroup.hidden = false
        }
        else
        {
            cell.imgDeleteGroup.hidden = true
            cell.btnDeleteGroup.hidden = true
        }
        */

    }



    return cell

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    let sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController_Contact.sections![indexPath.section] as NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo

    // Last Row of the TableView : Add Button
    if (indexPath.row == sectionInfo.numberOfObjects)
    {
        //tmp_0309
        /*
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SelectAddContactsTableViewControllerNav") as UINavigationController

        vc.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.width-20, self.view.bounds.height*1/2)

        vc.loadView()



        let vc2 = vc.viewControllers[0] as SelectAddContactsTableViewController
        vc2.delegateSelectAddContactsTableVcDelegate = self
        vc2.selectedGroupId = selectedGroupId




        popoverController_SelectAddContactsTableVc = WYPopoverController(contentViewController: vc)
        popoverController_SelectAddContactsTableVc.delegate = self
        popoverController_SelectAddContactsTableVc.presentPopoverFromRect(CGRectMake(self.collectionView.bounds.origin.x, self.collectionView.bounds.origin.y, self.collectionView.bounds.width, 50) , inView: self.view, permittedArrowDirections: WYPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)
        */


        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toSelectContactsVc", sender: self)



    }
    else
    {

        let modIndexPath : NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row, inSection: indexPath.section)
        var result = self.fetchedResultsController_Contact.objectAtIndexPath(modIndexPath) as? Contact

        contactIndex = indexPath.row

        let myRect : CGRect  = tableView.rectForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

        var myRectMod : CGRect = CGRect(x: myRect.origin.x, y: myRect.origin.y, width: 20, height: myRect.height)


        // Display ContactListDetailVc Popover
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ContactListDetailViewController") as ContactListDetailViewController

        vc.loadView()
        vc.delegateContactListDetailVcDelegate = self

        vc.contactId = result!.id as Int
        vc.title = "Contact Detail"
        //vc.btnCancel.addTarget(self, action: Selector("dismissCreateGroupVc"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)



        //vc.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake( self.view.bounds.width-50, self.view.bounds.height-85)
        vc.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake( self.view.bounds.width-20, 270)



        popoverController_ContactListDetailVc = WYPopoverController(contentViewController: vc)
        popoverController_ContactListDetailVc.delegate = self
        popoverController_ContactListDetailVc.presentPopoverFromRect(myRectMod, inView: self.tableView, permittedArrowDirections: WYPopoverArrowDirection.Up, animated: true)
        //popoverController.presentPopoverAsDialogAnimated(true, options: WYPopoverAnimationOptions.FadeWithScale)





    }


}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Bool {

    let sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController_Contact.sections![indexPath.section] as NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo

    // Last Row of the TableView : Add Button
    if (indexPath.row == sectionInfo.numberOfObjects)
    {
        return false
    }
    else
    {
        return true
    }

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
        // handle delete (by removing the data from your array and updating the tableview)


        let modIndexPath : NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row, inSection: indexPath.section)
        var result = self.fetchedResultsController_Contact.objectAtIndexPath(modIndexPath) as? Contact

        DataManager.instance.deleteContactFromGroup(selectedGroupId, contactId: result?.id as Int)


        /*
        if (groupIndex != 0 )
        {
            DataManager.instance.deleteContactFromGroup(groupId, contactId: DataManager.instance.contact_id[indexPath.row])
        }
        else
        {
            DataManager.instance.deleteSpecificContact(DataManager.instance.contact_id[indexPath.row])
        }
        */

        //DataManager.instance.group_id.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        //DataManager.instance.group_name.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        //DataManager.instance.group_iconId.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

        //tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

...

Comment: It's difficult to provide any other advice than "don't mutate collections while they're being enumerated". You'll need to find where your code does that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for informing! I am generating related screen shots now, and will update the question in a few minutes.

Comment: Sorry I can't post screen shots yet. The view is an Addressbook with : horizontal collection view at the top for managing 'groups', and a vertical table view to manage 'contacts', base on the crash report, seems like the error occurs on collection View.

Comment: Could you post the stack trace?

Comment: Hi John, I have posted the stack trace!   I have also try to symbolicate the error code, but I think the best I can have is "SIGSEGV"   This view is using a long NSpredicate for a fetchManager to load data from CoreData into collection view & table view.

I just recently found that if the fetch exceed 1000, it will crash locally. I wonder if that has something related to this.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have found the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my build setting...

Go to Edit Scheme > Archive > Build Configuration.

Simply change "release" to "debug" and the version for archive will be exactly the same as the version for local debugging.

Now the iTunes version works!!